# Extend MudBlazor palettes

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I have a .NET 7 Blazor Webassembly app that uses MudBlazor (newest version).

I would like to derive from the MudBlazor palette class in order to create a palette with more "MudColors", eg. colors for graphs that I want to define for both dark and light modes, and be able to access these new colors both in C# and by using CSS classes.

I haven't been able to find any documentation relating to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the documentation here: https://mudblazor.com/customization/overview#custom-themes

It is currently not possible to add new colors to the palet, but you can use mud colors like this in your css `color: var(--mud-palette-primary)`.

To add custom colors, you can add a class to the root if your layout.razor.  `<div class="@(_isDarkMode ? "--root-dark" : "")">`

And add those styles to a custom stylesheet like this:

```
:root {
    --custom-color: #518ebd;
}
.--root-dark {
    --custom-color: #383737;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I was not explicit enough in my question, but I need to be able to switch between light and dark mode when the built-in MudBlazor components switch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MudThemeProvider and MudThemeSelect
To build on what @Taco provided I'm bind the dark theme by using a flag which gets set by the MudSelect dropdown.

`<MudThemeProvider @ref="@_mudThemeProvider" @bind-IsDarkMode="@IsDarkMode" /> <MudDialogProvider />`

You can do something like this as well.

```
 Style="@($"color:{Theme.Palette.Dark};")"

 Style="@($"color: {(isFilled ? Colors.Pink.Darken3 : Colors.Orange.Darken3 )};")"
```

The second option uses a ternary expression so you can switch between your light and dark colors.